# How to format a number as part of a sum in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula in Google Sheets

```
="final cost: $"&sum(E2:E70)
```

and it looks like this

[image: sample output]

I would like it to be properly formatted like so:

```
$10,837.5
```

Please advise.

Comment: "Properly formatted" dollar values have 2 decimal places or none. A dollar figure with a single digit behind the decimal is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DOLLAR()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094071) function to return a localized currency format.

> Formats a number into the locale-specific currency format.

Like so:

```
="final cost: "&dollar(sum(E2:E70))
```

If you still want to place your own currency symbol, then use [`FIXED()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094075).

```
="final cost: $"&fixed(sum(E2:E70),2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Use [TEXT(number, format)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)

## Example

```
="final cost: "&TEXT(SUM(E2:E70),"$#,###,##0.00")
```

Result:

```
final cost: $10,837.50
```